# How to check for if else condition for highlighted text?

Tags: javascript, java, android, eclipse

I want to implement the `If` and `Else` condition for checking if the selected text is highlighted or not. I can highlight the text but don't know the `if()` condition for highlighted text to remove again. I searched a lot but did not get a clear answer. Here is my code for:

```
private void highlightTextCondition() {
    int selectionStart = bodyText.getSelectionStart();
    int selectionEnd = bodyText.getSelectionEnd();
    if (selectionStart > selectionEnd) {
        int temp = selectionEnd;
        selectionEnd = selectionStart;
        selectionStart = temp;
    }
    if (selectionEnd > selectionStart) {
        Spannable str = bodyText.getText();
        boolean exists = false;


        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (**want this statement here for highlight texted**) {
                str.removeSpan(*****);
                exists = false;
            }
        }

        if (!exists) {
            str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            exists = true;
        }

        bodyText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this but I am not sure how to remove only selected text highlight colour

```
 if (selectionEnd > selectionStart) {
        Spannable str = bodyText.getText();
        boolean exists = false;

        for (CharacterStyle span : str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, CharacterStyle.class)) {
            if (span instanceof BackgroundColorSpan)
                str.removeSpan(span);
            exists = true;
        }
        if (!exists) {
            str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }

        bodyText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is working for me but the only problem is that when I highlight the whole line and then unhighlight part of that highlighted line text, then it unhighlight the whole text line.